# Invalid identifier when selecting from table with fieldnames in lower case

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, identifier

I imported data from a csv file and created a new table. The first row was the header.

When I am trying to run some simple queries to these tables I get an *ORA-00904 invalid identifier* error.

The only difference between usual tables and the tables with imported data is that the fieldnames in the latter are in lower case, whereas in usual tables they are always in uppercase.

Could that be a reason for the error?

Comment: Did you try changing your queries to use lower case? Did it work? *note that I would expect a schema mismatch to be more likely but you really should show us some DDL & SQL.*

Comment: Yes, in fact I am always writing in lower case.. 
the query is:
select dpd_1 from test_proba
the table test_proba is table with imported data, it's DDL:

CREATE TABLE "DWH"."TEST_PROBA" 
   ( "credit_num" VARCHAR2(11 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "term_acc_open_date" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "date_final_pmt_exp" DATE, 
 "dpd_1" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "dpd_2" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "dpd_3" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "dpd_4" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, etc.....

Comment: Sorry for poor formatting of the comment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the `""` in your DDL then you make your column names case sensitive.

so if the DDL is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "DWH"."TEST_PROBA" ( "credit_num" VARCHAR2(11 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"term_acc_open_date" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"date_final_pmt_exp" DATE, "dpd_1" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"dpd_2" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"dpd_3" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"dpd_4" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
etc
```

Then you need to query like this:

```
SELECT "credit_num", "term_acc_open_date", etc...
FROM "TEST_PROBA"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you create column names in lower case (which can only be done using double-quotes), you have to reference them that way as well.

Due to the way Oracle upper-cases unquoted identifiers, you have to surround your column names with double-quotes everywhere you use them. Quick example using your provided DDL:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4b2ac/4)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE "TEST_PROBA" (
  "credit_num" VARCHAR2(11 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE
, "term_acc_open_date" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE
, "date_final_pmt_exp" DATE
, "dpd_1" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE
)
/

INSERT INTO test_proba (
  "credit_num"
, "term_acc_open_date"
, "date_final_pmt_exp"
, "dpd_1"
)
VALUES (
  '12341234123'
, SYSDATE
, SYSDATE+1
, 'foo'
)
/

COMMIT
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT "credit_num"
FROM test_proba
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4b2ac/4/0)**:

```
|  CREDIT_NUM |
---------------
| 12341234123 |
```

Note that `SELECT "credit_num"` works while `SELECT credit_num` does not, and yields the ORA-00904 error as you mention above.

Comment: Unbelievable, thank you Ben and Lieven =) That was exactly i didn't know I have to wrap the columnnames with double quotes in this case. I thought i was getting crazy)) Thank you @Ben!

Comment: Hiya, glad your problem has been solved, you're very welcome. You should probably mark one of the answers as accepted so that others can see your question has been answered.